# Add empty rows after certain records in a table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table which is ordered in a hierarchy [Parent, Child, Child2]....i have 4 columns that i used to order the records into the correct positions and i also need to add a blank row before each parent (or after the last child) but im not sure how to go about it

the column i am thinking about using is the ParentID column since its the same ID for the parent and all the children but i dont really want to setup a cursor to loop the table, is there another way i might do this?

The table is organized using a ORDER BY ParentID, Child1ID, Child2ID

Ex. Data

[DATA]-[Desc]-[ParentID]-[Child1ID]-[Child2ID]

Rec1 - Parent - PID1 - NULL - NULL

Rec2 - Child - PID1 - CID1 - NULL

Rec3 - Child2 - PID1 - CID1 - C2ID1

Rec4 - Child - PID1 - CID2 - NULL

Rec5 - Parent - PID2 - NULL - NULL

etc etc

Comment: Please add to the question the expected result and the version of SQL Server that you use.

Answer (score 0):

I just hope the Child2 is misprint

```
select 'child' as 'xxx', [ParentID], [Child1ID], [Child2ID]  
from ...  
union 
select distinct 'parent', [ParentID], null, null 
from ... 
order by [ParentID], xxx desc
```

Comment: no the child (level 2) is a third level into the data, i did howeverfigure it out using a method that looks similar to this but a little different

Answer (score 0):

I would use two row_number(), one as a surrogate PK using your order, and another one to partition based on each parent. Then I would get the marker where I can find each last child. When I multiply the surrogate PK to 10, I will be able to insert the blank line as tenth row + 5.

[Tested here](http://rextester.com/CXUI27695)

Comment: i will look into this, i did however get the result by fixing the table within the application i'm developing which was simple to setup with my current code there.